# Is there a plugin for Eclipse that allows two people to edit the same project at the same time?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

A friend and I want to work on the same project. Is there a way that we can work on the same project at the same time and have the files stored on Google Drive or Dropbox?

Comment: Yes, the plugins come in the form of version control software plugins. There are many available with eclipse integration.

Answer (score 3):

You really want to use a version control system, like [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com) or [git](http://git-scm.com). There are lots of hosting options for both of these, like [github](http://github.com), [bitbucket](http://bitbucket.com) and others.

Edit: As was observed in a comment, you may also take a look at Subversion or CVS. Whichever works best in your case.

As for Eclipse integration, there are solutions for most systems :

- http://javaforge.com/project/HGE for Mercurial
- http://www.eclipse.org/egit/ for Git
- http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/ for SVN

Comment: ...or svn or cvs, which I find to be better supported in Eclipse than git.

Comment: then is there a plugin to get for eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

You can Setup a remote git Server or use bitbucket
In Addition with egit for eclipse :) 
I Have done this yesterday and it works pretty well

//again too slow :P

Comment: If you are 'too slow' start going for quality posts and not quick answers. You can always expand your answer so its 'better' than the quick ones. ;)

Comment: Thx, yes thats right =)
but i was on mobile and thought , yay i did this yesterday =)
a post i can actually answer, =)
It just happened that the last 3 questions i could give an answer to,
already had a similar answer postet short before =) 
And i saw those always after i posted the answer

Its not that i want to be the first who answers or to have the 'better' answer, i just want to help the people , as i got really great and helpfull answers to my questions here =)